# Understanding ReentrantLocks and Thread basics

Tags: java

I am trying to write a basic program using threads. Assuming I have two threads, t1 and t2 and lock x. Assuming lock x is assigned to t1. When would be a situation where t2 would be unable to process due to lock x being assigned to t1? I am trying to create a simple example to demonstrate how locks/threads work.

I appreciate any assistance in this matter.

This is what I got so far:

Class Skywalker:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Skywalker{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t1 = new Thread("station 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread("station 2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Class Darth:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Darth implements Runnable{
    String stationName;
    Lock x = new ReentrantLock();
    Random r = new Random();

    public Darth(String name){
        stationName = name;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            x.lock();
            System.out.println(stationName + "is working");
            sleep(randomTime);
            x.unlock();

        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you get the code to compile first, that should be the easy bit.  Once you have done that you are very close to the solution.

Comment: Did you mean `Thread t1 = new Darth("station 1");` in class Skywalker?

Comment: How are you supposed to use class Darth?

Comment: I'd consider doing more logging in `Darth.run()`. I.e. before and after the lock is acquired and released.

Comment: Also, both of your threads will use a different lock object, and thus can never block one another.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use `ReentrantLock` here. The point of that class is to let a single thread acquire it "recursively" without blocking itself - no such thing is going on in your code. (Or would go on were there a single shared lock. Your code is rather confused and confusing.)

Comment: millimoose, thanks for the reply. I am here because I am trying to eliminate some of the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the lock in one single class to protect a "resource access", for instance:

```
class SharedResource {
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void consumeResource(){
        try{
            lock.lock();
            //just one thread a time here
            int i = 10;
            //mock consuming shared resource:
            while(i>0){
                i--;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is in");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }  
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
 }
```

Now just one thread a time will be able to access the lines of code in consumeResource method that are within the lock/unlock statements. It is easy to show that invoking consumeResource from Darth run method.